# I'm struggling with Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast' in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

This is my model class. It is a complex class that relies on two other classes outside with the names of `CountriesDatum`, `PayoutCurrenciesDatum`, `AccountType` and `Address` to get data but the problem is with the `ProofofPayment` class.

```
class RcipientInsertRequest {
  RcipientInsertRequest({
    this.proofOfPayments,
    this.branchCode,
    this.branchName,
    this.active,
    this.address,
    this.accountId,
    this.country,
    this.payoutCcy,
    this.name,
    this.bankName,
    this.accountType,
    this.accountNumber,
    this.recipientReference,
    this.ownerReference,
    this.authorizationCode,
  });

  ProofOfPayments proofOfPayments;
  String branchCode;
  String branchName;
  bool active;
  Address address;
  String accountId;
  CountriesDatum country;
  PayoutCurrenciesDatum payoutCcy;
  String name;
  String bankName;
  AccountType accountType;
  String accountNumber;
  String recipientReference;
  String ownerReference;
  String authorizationCode;

  factory RcipientInsertRequest.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => RcipientInsertRequest(
    proofOfPayments: json["proof_of_payments"] == null ? null : ProofOfPayments.fromJson(json["proof_of_payments"]),
    branchCode: json["branch_code"] == null ? null : json["branch_code"],
    branchName: json["branch_name"] == null ? null : json["branch_name"],
    active: json["active"] == null ? null : json["active"],
    address: json["address"] == null ? null : Address.fromJson(json["address"]),
    accountId: json["account_id"] == null ? null : json["account_id"],
    country: json["country"] == null ? null : CountriesDatum.fromJson(json["country"]),
    payoutCcy: json["payout_ccy"] == null ? null : PayoutCurrenciesDatum.fromJson(json["payout_ccy"]),
    name: json["name"] == null ? null : json["name"],
    bankName: json["bank_name"] == null ? null : json["bank_name"],
    accountType: json["account_type"] == null ? null : AccountType.fromJson(json["account_type"]),
    accountNumber: json["account_number"] == null ? null : json["account_number"],
    recipientReference: json["recipient_reference"] == null ? null : json["recipient_reference"],
    ownerReference: json["owner_reference"] == null ? null : json["owner_reference"],
    authorizationCode: json["authorization_code"] == null ? null : json["authorization_code"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "proof_of_payments": proofOfPayments == null ? null : proofOfPayments.toJson(),
    "branch_code": branchCode == null ? null : branchCode,
    "branch_name": branchName == null ? null : branchName,
    "active": active == null ? null : active,
    "address": address == null ? null : address.toJson(),
    "account_id": accountId == null ? null : accountId,
    "country": country == null ? null : country.toJson(),
    "payout_ccy": payoutCcy == null ? null : payoutCcy.toJson(),
    "name": name == null ? null : name,
    "bank_name": bankName == null ? null : bankName,
    "account_type": accountType == null ? null : accountType.toJson(),
    "account_number": accountNumber == null ? null : accountNumber,
    "recipient_reference": recipientReference == null ? null : recipientReference,
    "owner_reference": ownerReference == null ? null : ownerReference,
    "authorization_code": authorizationCode == null ? null : authorizationCode,
  };
}
```

`Proof of Payments`I am using quicktype io to create my classes

```
class ProofOfPayments {
  ProofOfPayments({
    this.data,
  });

  List<Datum> data;


    factory ProofOfPayments.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ProofOfPayments(
      data: json["data"] == null ? null : List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
      "data": data == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
  }



class Datum {
  Datum();

  factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
  };
}
```

Here you can see my post method.

```
Future<bool> recipientInsert(RcipientInsertRequest rcipientInsertRequest)async{
    String url ="confidential";

    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url) ,headers:{
      HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader:'Bearer '+StaticVars.apiKey
    },body: rcipientInsertRequest.toJson());
    if(response.statusCode==200){
      StaticVars.statusCode = response.statusCode;

      //return RcipientInsertResponce.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
      return true;
    }else{
      StaticVars.statusCode = response.statusCode;

      throw Exception('fail to load data');

    }
  }
```

Here you can see the json responds. I am working on pre existing api so I can't change it

```
{
   "proof_of_payments":{
      "data":[
         {
            
         }
      ]
   },
   "branch_code":"1234564",
   "branch_name":"",
   "active":true,
   "address":{
      "latitude":-29.1680844,
      "longitude":26.1748719,
      "number":"12",
      "street":"Pellissier Drive",
      "city":"Bloemfontein",
      "state":"FS",
      "country":"South Africa",
      "zip":"9322",
      "formatted":"12 Pellissier Dr, Pellissier, Bloemfontein, 9322, South Africa",
      "placeId":"ChIJeQcn0UnEjx4RZHxhZBKXKZI"
   },
   "account_id":"82d4c1f6-60b2-42d1-baba-4b8820f9b0fe",
   "country":{
      "country_code":"ZA",
      "three_digit_code":"ZAF",
      "long_name":"South Africa",
      "alt_name":"",
      "payout_ccys":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "country_code":"ZA",
            "ccy":"ZAR",
            "created_at":"2016-05-17 17:06:25",
            "updated_at":"2016-05-17 17:06:25"
         },
         {
            "id":53,
            "country_code":"ZA",
            "ccy":"USD",
            "created_at":"2019-02-07 09:22:57",
            "updated_at":"2019-02-07 09:23:04"
         },
         {
            "id":58,
            "country_code":"ZA",
            "ccy":"EUR",
            "created_at":"2019-07-24 13:40:26",
            "updated_at":"2019-07-24 13:40:28"
         }
      ],
      "payout_currencies":{
         "data":[
            {
               "country_code":"ZA",
               "ccy":"ZAR"
            },
            {
               "country_code":"ZA",
               "ccy":"USD"
            },
            {
               "country_code":"ZA",
               "ccy":"EUR"
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "payout_ccy":{
      "country_code":"ZA",
      "ccy":"ZAR"
   },
   "name":"mako",
   "bank_name":"absa",
   "account_type":{
      "id":"SAVINGS",
      "name":"Savings Account"
   },
   "account_number":"4567879123",
   "recipient_reference":"rent",
   "owner_reference":"rent",
   "authorization_code":"454949"
}
```

Here you can see the error.

```
I/flutter ( 2130): 1232464 true South Africa ZA ZAR piet absa Savings Account 13165487 test test 1234 
E/flutter ( 2130): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast
E/flutter ( 2130): #0      CastMap.forEach.<anonymous closure> (dart:_internal/cast.dart:288:25)
E/flutter ( 2130): #1      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:397:8)
E/flutter ( 2130): #2      CastMap.forEach (dart:_internal/cast.dart:287:13)
E/flutter ( 2130): #3      mapToQuery (package:http/src/utils.dart:17:7)
E/flutter ( 2130): #4      Request.bodyFields= (package:http/src/request.dart:137:12)
E/flutter ( 2130): #5      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:87:17)
E/flutter ( 2130): #6      BaseClient.post (package:http/src/base_client.dart:32:7)
E/flutter ( 2130): #7      post.<anonymous closure> (package:http/http.dart:69:16)
E/flutter ( 2130): #8      _withClient (package:http/http.dart:164:20)
E/flutter ( 2130): #9      post (package:http/http.dart:68:5)
E/flutter ( 2130): #10     ServicesOut.recipientInsert (package:inter_africa_app/services/ServicesOut.dart:32:28)
E/flutter ( 2130): #11     _CreateRecipientState.authDialog.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:inter_africa_app/views/CreateRecipient.dart:85:33)
E/flutter ( 2130): #12     _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:989:21)
E/flutter ( 2130): #13     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
E/flutter ( 2130): #14     TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:607:11)
E/flutter ( 2130): #15     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:296:5)
E/flutter ( 2130): #16     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:230:7)
E/flutter ( 2130): #17     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:475:9)
E/flutter ( 2130): #18     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:93:12)
E/flutter ( 2130): #19     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:138:9)
E/flutter ( 2130): #20     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:397:8)
E/flutter ( 2130): #21     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:136:18)
E/flutter ( 2130): #22     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:122:7)
E/flutter ( 2130): #23     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:439:19)
E/flutter ( 2130): #24     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:419:22)
E/flutter ( 2130): #25     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:287:11)
E/flutter ( 2130): #26     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:374:7)
E/flutter ( 2130): #27     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:338:5)
E/flutter ( 2130): #28     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:296:7)
E/flutter ( 2130): #29     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:279:7)
E/flutter ( 2130): #30     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1370:13)
E/flutter ( 2130): #31     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)
E/flutter ( 2130): #32     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1170:7)
E/flutter ( 2130): #33     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:182:10)
E/flutter ( 2130): #34     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:282:7)
E/flutter ( 2130): #35     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:96:31)
E/flutter ( 2130):
```

I beg of anyone that can help me please help

Comment: Can you provide your `ProofofPayment` class?

Comment: I hope this will help you help me

Comment: From your stack trace, it looks like the error is in preparing the request to send (specifically, setting the body fields). Do you get the same error just running `rcipientInsertRequest.toJson()` without attempting to make a HTTP request?

Comment: Oh, I think I see it. As per https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Client/post.html - "If body is a Map, it's encoded as form fields using encoding. The content-type of the request will be set to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; this cannot be overridden." and additionally, in the implementation (https://github.com/dart-lang/http/blob/e89b190936d53d0e36148436283e28ba1091b35a/lib/src/base_client.dart#L87) it tries to cast to `Map<String,String>` which fails later on. Try passing `json.encode(rcipientInsertRequest.toJson())` as the `body` parameter.